# (angular) js: from date and time picker to epoch time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, epoch

I am writing a frontend for rest api that uses epoch time (milliseconds). I am using date and time picker from [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). How to create epoch time from the given values?

How to create readable dates from epoch i learned [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). But i can't find a solution for other direction (give time format and create epoch time from a string).

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker / scope variable should be an instance of a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, and then you can call [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) on it:

```
new Date(2015, 6, 5).getTime()
```

Comment: ok, but i also need to take time from timepicker into account - or is there a way to also select time in datepicker?